# How to copy row if it contains certain text to another sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that copies a row if a cell in that row contains text (For ex: Mumbai, Delhi etc) from Column C.

For example if there are 30 rows but only 15 contains text(Mumbai & Delhi) in column C. I want to copy those 15 rows and paste them into "Sheet2"
I was using the below code. however it only copying "Mumbai". I need the for loop go through the same column and copy "Delhi" as well.

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 7 To lastrow
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = "Mumbai" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).copy
erow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1,1)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1,2)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Please let me know how can use And function in the above code. or any other way to copy it into sheet2.
Thank you.

Comment: I suppose that instead of "Mumbai & Delhi" you need "Mumbai" **or** "Delhi"... Is my supposition correct?

Comment: I need both Mumbai & Delhi needs to be copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. You must use **your used sheets name**:

```
Sub testPasteinSh2()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range
 Dim rngCopy As Range, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long
 Dim strSearch1 As String, strSearch2 As String
 
 strSearch1 = "Mumbai" 'or combo value...
 strSearch2 = "Delhi"  'or something else...
 Set sh1 = ActiveSheet          'use here your worksheet
 Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'use here your sheet
 lastR1 = sh1.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastR2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
 Set rng = sh1.Range("C2:C" & lastR1)
 For Each cel In rng.cells
    If cel.Value = strSearch1 Or cel.Value = strSearch2 Then
        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopy = sh1.Rows(cel.Row)
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, sh1.Rows(cel.Row))
        End If
    End If
 Next
 If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then
    rngCopy.Copy Destination:=sh2.cells(lastR2, 1)
 End If
End Sub
```

It should be very fast, keeping the rows to be copied in a Union range and paste everything at once.

It will even be more efficient if you do not need the rows format. Array can be used. And not the whole row to be copied, only its filled part...

Answer (score 0):

-Try to make a for loop

-Example copies from sheet 1 to sheet 2

```
Dim i As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
dim sh2 As worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
For i = 1 To Application.CountA( sh.Range("C:C"))
```

-by defining the if statements you can controll what values are copied

-make an if statement in the loop controlling if the value is not blank

-refer to cell with loopvalue

-copy :)

```
if sh.Range("C" & i).Value <> "" then

sh.Range("C" & i).Copy (sh2)

end if

Next i
```

Comment: The way of  range to be processed last row calculation is not the best. If there are empty rows/cells, there will be missed rows. Then, your code does not search for any string (like Mumbai...). No necessary to check against empty. Only cells having the value of string to be searched will be processed. Then he needs to copy al row, and finally copying of each cell is not the most efficient way, since other methods (copying at once) are better...